# AVQueuePlayer play a series of clips without hiccuping

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer, avqueueplayer

I have a series of video clips in an AVQueuePlayer. How do I transition between them without a pause or delay?

By default, it looks like there's a half second hiccup when transitioning between `clip1.mp4` and `clip2.mp4`

All clips are local to the device.